# db2 locked table, how to find pid of blocking processs

Tags: database, db2

I have little knowledge of db2 administration, and I can't figure out how to find the pid of the process locking the tab tables.

With db2top (screen "U"), I have the following table:

> ```
> Agent        Application  Application    Object              Lock     Object     Lock       Lock  Is      Locked   Tablespace
> Id(State)    Name         Status         Name                Mode     Type       Status     Count Blocker By       Name
> ------------ ------------ -------------- ------------------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----- ------- -------- -----------
>      7060(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   YYYY01.TABLEZZ      IS       Table      Granted        1      No     7974 USERSPACE1
>      7060(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   Internal Variation  S        Variation  Granted        1      No     7974 -
>      7060(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   YYYY01.TABLEZZ[0]   NS [X]   Row        -              -      No     7974 USERSPACE1
>      7060(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   Internal Plan       S        Plan       Granted        1      No     7974 -
>      7974(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   Internal Variation  S        Variation  Granted        1     Yes     8080 -
>      7974(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   YYYY01.TABLEZZ[0]   X [U]    Row        -              -     Yes     8080 USERSPACE1
>      7974(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   Internal Plan       S        Plan       Granted        1     Yes     8080 -
>      7974(l) xxxxxxxxxx   Lock Waiting   YYYY01.TABLEZZ      IX       Table      Granted        1     Yes     8080 USERSPACE1
> ```

I have figured out that Agent 7974 is the blocking one. I'ld like to kill it and fix/test the bug.
How can I figure out the pid of agent 7974 so I can attach a gdb to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is kill the agent, you can do it with `db2 force application (7974)`. The client process ID is shown in `db2top` on the session screen (press `l`). You can also use  `db2pd -db <your database> -agents app=7974`

Comment: I'ld like to attach a gdb to it before having to kill it in order to figure out where and why the bug (lock) occurs.
I'll try the 'db2pd ... app=7974' command.

Comment: I think it might be easier to use DB2 tools to diagnose database problems -- e.g. as described in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0055234.html